# Finding Workspace in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I find the workspace I'm currently working on in Eclipse? Is there a way to do it with the GUI and the drop down menus instead of typing in commands? I tried that and it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though is the operation to switch workspace it will show you the current workspace

**File** > **Switch** > **Other...**

Or less convenient but the real method i think

**Navigate** > **Open Setup** > **Open Workspace**

Open a dialog witch show the current workspace

Comment: No one is notified by your comments... The question did  ask "show current workspace"

Comment: I understand you're correct, but there is no reason to clutter StackOverflow with duplicate questions or answers